# How to drop multiple HBase tables using Java?

Tags: hbase

When using command line, I can drop several tables using `disable_all` and `drop_all`, but in Java API, I didn't find any simple way to achieve the purpose. So how to do this just using java API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HBase Java API provides a method `HBaseAdmin.disableTables(String regex)`